# C# DbContext has been disposed when trying to access a cached list

Tags: c#, entity, dbcontext

I am using `System.Runtime.Caching` to save a list of entities in my program cache, the Add and Get method are working succesfully, the lists have the size they must.

But when i try to access one of the values i always obtain the same exception  `DbContext has been disposed`

A example of the access:

```
listaRelTareasOrquestador = (List<GesBrokerSuiteEntities>)cache.Get("listaOrquestador");

foreach (GesBrokerSuiteEntities registro in listaRelTareasOrquestador) {

     using (GesBrokerSuiteEntities ctx = new GesBrokerSuiteEntities()) {

          rel_tareas_orquestador nuevoregistroOrquestador = new rel_tareas_orquestador();

          nuevoregistroOrquestador.id_robot_hija = listaRelTareasOrquestador[0].rel_tareas_orquestador.FirstOrDefault().id_robot_padre;
          nuevoregistroOrquestador.id_robot_padre = registro.rel_tareas_orquestador.FirstOrDefault().id_robot_padre;
                   
          ctx.rel_tareas_orquestador.Add(nuevoregistroOrquestador);

          ctx.SaveChanges();

     }
                    
}
```

Both accessing lines throws the exception, I tried both ways to check the error, how could the values of `nuevoregistroOrquestador` be accessed?

Comment: Is nuevoregistroOrquestador null?

Comment: @jdweng no, is a created instance of my table rel_tareas_orquestador

Comment: Get listaRelTareasOrquestador Count() value

Comment: @jdweng 3, the elements are in the list, but are disposed i think.

Comment: Move following line before the "using" so it does not get disposed : rel_tareas_orquestador nuevoregistroOrquestador = new rel_tareas_orquestador();

Comment: @jdweng is disposed when i call the get method, thats de problem. Does the class dispose de DbContext after the Add?

Comment: Remove the using statement.  ctx is getting disposed when you leave the using block.